# git: How to create a branch of my current work, but stay on my original branch

Tags: git, save, branch

I'm on a branch (let's say master), and I have some changes in my working dir.  I get stuff working, but needing a lot of cleanup - so I'd like to save my current working dir to a branch just in case I need to go back to it.  I'll definitely be deleting the branch later.

In addition, I want to continue working on master EXACTLY where I was.

Right now I do:

```
# Save to topic branch
git checkout -b working-stuff
git commit -a -m "work in progress"

# go back to master and continue with the state is was in before
git checkout master
git checkout -- .
git reset
```

Later on, I'll delete the topic branch.

So, the above does exactly what I want, but its a bit verbose.  Is there a simpler way to do this (besides just scripting it)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
 git stash
```

From the manual

> Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The
>          command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the HEAD commit.

With `git stash` you stash your modifications, then you can apply them again with:

```
 git stash apply
```

Or you can list your stashed modifications with:

```
 git stash list
```

Comment: Just as a further note, `git stash` is basically implemented as a branch.

Comment: Perfect - that's what I was looking for - I see that git stash has a lot more options than just a simple save/pop that I've used before.  So, the better method for me is simply: `git stash; git stash apply`.  Which does exactly what I want, plus automatically gives me a more informative WIP message, and there's not need to remove the branch later if I don't need it.

Comment: @thebriguy I suggest to clean up stale stashes using `stash drop`; lots of left over stashes can become confusing when you use `stash list`.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness sake: If you want a proper branch (which has some advantages over a stash), you don’t need to use plumbing commands, you can also do:

```
git add -A .
git commit -m "dirty"
git branch dirtybranch
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ git add bar

$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   bar
#

$ git branch newbar $(echo wip | git commit-tree \
  $(git write-tree) -p $(git rev-parse HEAD))

$ git lola --name-status
* e3f88c8 (newbar) wip
| A     bar
* a7b1a76 (HEAD, master) foo
  A     foo
```

Just because you *can* doesn’t mean you *should*.