# Git - temporarily save current work

Tags: git

I'm adding a feature on master branch. After changing several files, I realize that I need to check the output without my changes.

The way I can think of is:

1. Commit current changes
2. Check out and switch to a new branch
3. In the new branch: `git reset --hard HEAD^` so that I get back to the original code.
4. Try the code and when I'm done, switch back to master branch and delete this new branch.

Is there a better way for this?

Can I save a snapshot of current changes and come back later when I am ready?

Comment: Use [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing), or did I miss something?

Comment: You don't actually need a new branch to do your original plan; just `git checkout HEAD^`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2944469/1484957

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: How to create a branch of my current work, but stay on my original branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917636/git-how-to-create-a-branch-of-my-current-work-but-stay-on-my-original-branch)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply use `git stash`, which will store away your change to the local working tree. Then do your things, and when you're done, `git stash pop` to get things back. See the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) about stashing.

Comment: But git stash pop could cause merge conflict. I don't want to merge, I just want to all modify restore to working index.

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly what [`stashing`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) is designed for.

Basically:

1. Use `git stash save` to save your changes in a side location (i.e., the stash)
2. Check whatever you want, fix if needed, and commit
3. Use `git stash pop` to return your changes to the working directory.

Comment: I did not have to use git stash save. I just used git stash and then git pop.